# How to use an external file for database configuration in EJB environment

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

I need to have a file for database configuration outside of EAR file of my EJB application. Even if I define a datasource and call it via JNDI, I still have some properties that I want to change, like hibernate.dialect or hibernate.show_sql, for example.
I tried using:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="some-file.xml" />
```

and it works fine when some-file.xml is in jar file, but how to call it from another location. I tried file:/// but didn´t work.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with `/some-file.xml` and put your `some-file.xml` on the classpath.